React Native screens Android build failed due to CMake
unable to make build on Android giving error:
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

> Task :react-native-screens:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
C/C++: /Users/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/CMakeLists.txt debug|arm64-v8a : com.google.prefab.api.NoMatchingLibraryException: No compatible library found for //ReactAndroid/hermestooling. Rejected the following libraries:
425 actionable tasks: 44 executed, 381 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 

I've updated React Native version from 0.73.4 to 0.76.5 using react native upgrade helper and update other libraries also. IOS build is successfully running but giving error on android. I've also updated react-native-screens version to ^4.4.0.
